# Difference between boost optional and std::experimental optional assignment

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, gcc4.9, boost-optional

Usually when a function returns `boost::optional` I've seen a lot of people returning an empty brace `{}` to designate an empty value, that works fine and is shorter than returning `boost::none`.

I tried to do something similar to empty a `boost::optional<int>`, but when calling the copy assignment operator (or most probably the move assignment op) with an empty brace in the right side, the empty brace is converted to an int and then that value is assigned to the optional, so I end up with the variable set to 0 and not an empty value as I was expecting. Here's an example https://godbolt.org/g/HiF92v, if I try the same with `std::experimental::optional` I get the result I'm expecting (just replace with std::experimental::optional in the example and you will see that the instruction becomes `mov eax, eax`).

Also if I try with a different template argument for the boost optional (a non integer type) some compilers compile (with the behavior I'm expecting, an example here http://cpp.sh/5j7n) and others don't. So even for the same lib the behavior is different according to the template arg.

I'd like to understand what is going on here, I know it has something to do with the fact that I'm using a C++14 feature for a library that doesn't consider that into the design. I read the `boost/optional` header but I got lost in the details, I also tried to study the compiled code without inlining with a similar result.

I'm using gcc 4.9.2 with -std=c++14 and boost 1.57.

btw: I known I should have used `boost::optional::reset` or `boost::none`, but I was trying to be consistent with the semantics in the rest of the code base.

Comment: There's a difference between assignment and initialization...

Comment: yes sure, but the question is, why the assignment is different between boost::optional and std::experimental::optional, and why this work for boost::optional with non integer types

Comment: Basically, `std::experimental::optional` plays some special tricks to ensure that `o = {}` always resets it. `boost::optional` doesn't have those tricks.

Comment: Note that in Boost 1.63 this problem is fixed: `boost::optional` behaves in the same way as `std::opitonal`: `o = {}` is always a reset to no-value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To understand what is going on, consider this example first:

```
void fun(int) { puts("f int"); }
void fun(double) { puts("f double"); }

int main() {
  fun({}); // error
}
```

This results in a compiler error, because the overload resolution is inconclusive: `double` and `int` fit equally well. But, if a non-scalar type comes into play, the situation is different:

```
struct Wrap{};
void fun(int) { puts("f(int)"); }
void fun(Wrap) { puts("f(Wrap)"); }

int main() {
  fun({}); // ok: f(int) selected
}
```

This is because a scalar is a better match. If, for some reason, I want the same two overloads but at the same time I would like `fun({})` to select overload `fun(Wrap)`, I can tweak the definitions a bit:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, std::decay_t<T>>::value>
fun(T) { puts("f int"); }

void fun(Wrap) { puts("f(Wrap)"); }
```

That is, `fun(Wrap)` remains unchanged, but the first overload is now a template that takes any `T`. But with `enable_if` we constrain it, so that it only works with type `int`. So, this is quite an 'artificial' template, but it does the job. If I call:

```
fun(0); // picks fun(T)
```

The artificial template gets selected. But if I type:

```
fun({}); // picks fun(Wrap)
```

The artificial template is still a template, so it is never considered in type deduction in this case, and the only visible overload is `fun(Wrap)`, so it gets selected.

The same trick is employed in `std::optional<T>`: it does not have an assignment from `T`. Instead it has a similar artificial assignment template that takes any `U`, but is later constrained, so that `T == U`. You can see it in the reference implementation [here](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/blob/master/optional.hpp#L460-L466).

`boost::optional<T>` has been implemented before C++11, unaware of this 'reset idiom'. Therefore it has a normal assignment from `T`, and in cases where `T` happens to be a scalar this assignment from `T` is preferred. Hence the difference.

Given all that, I think that Boost.Optional has a bug that it does something opposite than `std::optional`. Even if it is not implementable in Boost.Optional, it should at least fail to compile, in order to avoid run-time surprises.